# The jquery only selects the first group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I am creating a system where the user can create a form.
So I do not know the name of the radio button.
The user can create as much diverent radio buttons as he likes.
If the script starts I want to checked al first radio buttons from a kind.
The jquery I made however only select the first.
Somebody has an answer:

```
<div class="formElement">
Eieren<br>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">ja</p>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">nee</p>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>

<div class="formElement">
Peren<br>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">ja</p>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">nee</p>
<p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>

<script>
$(".formElement p:eq(0) :radio").attr("checked", "checked");
</script>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqedj.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**.find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get first `p` of each item(which return from `$(".formElement")`) and again find to get first radio of each element return from previous find(). You can use the following code:

```js
$(".formElement")
 .find("p:eq(0)")//returns first p element's that match selector
 .find(":radio")//returns first radio element's that match previous selector
 .prop("checked", true);//set check to true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formElement">
  Eieren
  <br>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">ja</p>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">nee</p>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>

<div class="formElement">
  Peren
  <br>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">ja</p>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">nee</p>
  <p class="white">
    <input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>
```

**References:**

[:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:first-of-type`](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) pseudo selector like following.

```js
$(".formElement p:first-of-type  :radio").prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formElement">
    Eieren<br>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">ja</p>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">nee</p>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="eieren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>

<div class="formElement">
    Peren<br>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">ja</p>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">nee</p>
    <p class="white"><input type="radio" name="peren" class="formEl">soms</p>
</div>
```